# How to create a SQL Server Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I am trying to create a SQL Server `PIVOT` table but I having trouble.

Here is the result I want to get:

[image]

Here is the SQL query I have prepared but I am lost. How can I make this to work.

```
select *
from
    (select DESCRIPTION_, DISPLAYNAME, SUCCESFULRECORDCOUNT, FINISHDATETIME
     from LOGTABLE (NOLOCK)
    ) as X
pivot
     (sum(SUCCESFULRECORDCOUNT) for FINISHDATETIME in (GETDATE()-4)) as DAY1
pivot
     (sum(SUCCESFULRECORDCOUNT) for FINISHDATETIME in (GETDATE()-3)) as DAY2
pivot
     (sum(SUCCESFULRECORDCOUNT) for FINISHDATETIME in (GETDATE()-2)) as DAY2
pivot
     (sum(SUCCESFULRECORDCOUNT) for FINISHDATETIME in (GETDATE()-1)) as DAY3
```

Comment: `IN (GETDATE()-4, GETDATE()-3, GETDATE()-2, GETDATE()-1)`?

Comment: I want to display the past 4 days seperately

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, but it gives the error "Incorrect syntax near '('." gor getdate()

Comment: You have a couple issues here. First is using shorthand for dateadd. This is not a good habit to get into. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations Second, look what is returned from getdate() - 4. It is a datetime, not a date. You would need to convert that to a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=915122598b6f8f350127f79e21b3c12c

You need to change your dates into literal values to use in the pivot.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    DESCRIPTION_,
    DISPLAYNAME,
    CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, FINISHDATETIME, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(1))  AS dateNum,
    SUCCESFULRECORDCOUNT
  FROM
    test
  WHERE
    FINISHDATETIME >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
)
  data
PIVOT
(
  SUM(SUCCESFULRECORDCOUNT) FOR dateNum IN ([4], [3], [2], [1])
)
  pvt
;
```

Comment: that looks great thanks. I am tryinh this now. can I add LastFinishDate as last column?

Comment: @ArifYILMAZ Just try it?

Answer (score 1):

i think you can just use group by like

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION_,DISPLAYNAME
,SUM(IIF(FINISHDATETIME IN (GETDATE()-4),SUCCESFULRECORDCOUNT,0)) AS 'DAY1'
,SUM(IIF(FINISHDATETIME IN (GETDATE()-3),SUCCESFULRECORDCOUNT,0)) AS 'DAY2'
,SUM(IIF(FINISHDATETIME IN (GETDATE()-2),SUCCESFULRECORDCOUNT,0)) AS 'DAY3'
,SUM(IIF(FINISHDATETIME IN (GETDATE()-1),SUCCESFULRECORDCOUNT,0)) AS 'DAY4'
FROM LOGTABLE  (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY 
DESCRIPTION_,
DISPLAYNAME
```

Comment: Remove `SUCCESFULRECORDCOUNT,FINISHDATETIME` from the `SELECT` and `FINISHDATETIME` from the `GROUP BY`

Comment: that makes sense